# Cabal - Expose all modules while building library

Tags: haskell, cabal

Is it possible to tell `Cabal` to expose all modules while building a library?

Right now I have to provide very long list of modules in the `exposed-modules` cabal configurtion file section.

Comment: Are you asking how to incorporate a module in a cabal project without mentioning it in the `.cabal` file?

Comment: @Heatsink, no - If you are compiling a library with cabal you have to write `<...>.cabal` configuration file. In this file you ave to provide section `Exposed-modules` in which you have to list **every** module you want to expose. I want to expose **all** the modules.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Every module must be listed in the `.cabal` file.  Internal modules must be listed, too, in `Other-modules`.  Are you asking for alternative ways of listing all modules, or are you asking for ways of using a module without listing it?

Comment: @Heatsin: sorry for my missunderstanding. I was asking for alternative ways of listing all modules, but I would love to know ways of using a module without listing it also :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The modern answer is [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/) + [hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack#readme) instead of using explicit cabal config. It could automatically expose package modules and provides many other enhancements.

Answer (score 11):

You have to list all modules in the cabal configuration file.  In your case, you just put the list of modules after `exposed-modules:`.  There is no simpler way to write a list of modules.

Cabal cannot automatically find the files that are part of an executable or library, so it relies on the list of modules in the configuration file.  Unlike GHC, cabal cannot find modules based on import statements in the source code.  If you don't list every module, then you may be able to build the project (because GHC can find source files), but other commands such as `cabal sdist` will not access the source files that aren't listed.

Comment: If you run `cabal init` on a non-Cabalised source tree, it will populate `exposed-modules` automatically, but you'll still need to update the field manually afterwards.

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov This is pretty ridiculous. It can parse the import statements on "init" (which probably no one ever uses), but it can't do the same for any other command. This is definitely an issue.

Comment: Are there any external tools that can update `exposed-modules`? Or can `stack` do it?