# How to auto-populate "exposed-modules or other-modules" in *.cabal

Tags: cabal, haskell-stack

Somewhat annoyingly, I keep getting this warning (for some oh 20 modules or so, polluting the build output I'd otherwise see without scrolling such as actual ghc warnings etc):

**"The following modules should be added to exposed-modules or other-modules in `proj-name`.cabal**

with:

- a freshly created (via `stack new proj-name simple`) project,
- with its `.cabal` set to only contain an `executable proj-name` (no `library`),
- where I then right after `stack new ..` copied the `src` files/sub-dirs over from a non-stack/cabal project.

What's the supposed workflow here, am I seriously to manually keep those modules listings in the `.cabal` in sync with my module files?

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084265/cabal-expose-all-modules-while-building-library) someone suggests "the modern answer is Stack (and hpack)" but I was really hoping stack alone would somehow suffice here or could be set up to. If I am to set up **yet-another** (3rd after stack and thus implicitly cabal) tool just for builds, might as well go back to build scripts invoking ghc..

So the question: how can the overall very flexible powerful and robust stack help overcome also *this* cabal abomination, too?  =)

Comment: I think your best option is still hpack. Stack calls `hpack` when it finds a `package.yaml` file, so you don't have to call `hpack` manually. To derive a `package.yaml` from an existing .cabal file, use [hpack-convert](https://github.com/yamadapc/hpack-convert#readme) which you can simply install via `stack install hpack-convert`.